# icon with custom text like facebook,twitter

Tags: css, icons

I want icons (or some thing that looks like icon) with custom text on it.
So far i work [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BluAngel/xvxw4/1/) (i am not designer)
is there icons available like facebook, twitter but text on it not `f` but it should be `mi` etc

**Try**

HTML

```
<div class="mainContainer">
    <span>mi</span>
    <span class="split">km</span>
    <span class="split">ft</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.split
{
    border-left: thin solid #ff0000;
}
.mainContainer
{
    margin:4px;
    padding:4px;
    background-color:ButtonShadow;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

but this is too rough

Update
i want like that but required `mi` instead of `fb`

[image]

Comment: you can use this site for custom icons. http://fontello.com/

Comment: can you please tell me how the change icon on this site because i am changing and nothing happen

Comment: you says you want icon with custom text. so correct me do you want like this `facebook text with facebook icon`?

Comment: no. did you see my fiddle i provided in question. i need icon and text on that `mi`, `km`

Comment: do you want like this? http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/xvxw4/2/

Comment: i want icon which show `mi`. as there is icon for fb which show `f`.

Comment: I am sorry but still I cannot understand you.. would be better if you can share it by some diagram

Comment: you can use a font instead icon http://jsfiddle.net/xvxw4/4/

Comment: I've share my answer, please check below.

Answer (score 1):

you mean that you wanted these three icons?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

do you want the icon should look like this. check the **[Demo1](http://jsbin.com/cosalazo/1/)** and [**Demo2**](http://jsbin.com/cosalazo/2/).

```
.mainContainer > span
{
    width: 100px;
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    position:relative;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}

.mainContainer > span:first-child:before
{
    position:absolute;
    content: "mi";
    color:red;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    padding: 5px;
    background:gold;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font-size:1.5em;
    text-indent:0;
}
```

Comment: Is this you are looking for?

Comment: actually i was looking like this http://jsfiddle.net/xvxw4/4/ that posted in comments by   @GCyrillus.  Anyways your answer also very helpful

Comment: @Blu Angel if you are using `font icon` library like FontAwesome. In that case above code will work. you have to only add the uni-code in `content`. But thanks for the kind reply :)